# Folder search for title "contains" is doing a fuzzy search, not exact

Tags: google-drive-api

Using the 'q' parameter to search for a folder, I'm getting back a fuzzy match result which I wasn't expecting.  In the case below, I'm searching for "#731#", and getting a result back that is "#7311#".  Since the latter string does not actually contain the former, I did not expect that result.

FYI this is actually a call being made by Zapier -- it's using v2 and so I don't have the option to move to v3.

Below is the raw output of the API call:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
REQUEST
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?maxResults=5&q=title+contains+%27%23731%23%27+and+trashed+%3D+false+and+mimeType+%3D+%27application%2Fvnd.google-apps.folder%27+and+%271oSVTT56an_b9j_2v36YYL0RttSTMxacT%27+in+parents&supportsAllDrives=true&includeTeamDriveItems=true

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RESPONSE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

200

Expires: Sun, 09 Aug 2020 23:07:40 GMT
Date: Sun, 09 Aug 2020 23:07:40 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-transform
Etag: "qE31rY2igMHAxggaw96n3Xtt01o"
Vary: Origin, X-Origin
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self'
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
Server: GSE
Alt-Svc: h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-27=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

{
  "kind": "drive#fileList",
  "etag": "\"qE31rY2igMHAxggaw96n3Xtt01o\"",
  "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?includeTeamDriveItems=true&maxResults=5&q=title+contains+'%23731%23'+and+trashed+%3D+false+and+mimeType+%3D+'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'+and+'1oSVTT56an_b9j_2v36YYL0RttSTMxacT'+in+parents&supportsAllDrives=true",
  "incompleteSearch": false,
  "items": [{
    "kind": "drive#file",
    "id": "12xY5YicH_xwEffZ3hKWSB-VRJXGKdr_C",
    "etag": "\"MTU5NjgxODAxMjYyMA\"",
    "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/12xY5YicH_xwEffZ3hKWSB-VRJXGKdr_C",
    "alternateLink": "https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/12xY5YicH_xwEffZ3hKWSB-VRJXGKdr_C",
    "embedLink": "https://drive.google.com/embeddedfolderview?id=12xY5YicH_xwEffZ3hKWSB-VRJXGKdr_C",
    "iconLink": "https://drive-thirdparty.googleusercontent.com/16/type/application/vnd.google-apps.folder+shared",
    "title": "#7311#",
    "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder",
    "labels": {
      "starred": false,
      "hidden": false,
      "trashed": false,
      "restricted": false,
      "viewed": true
    },
    "copyRequiresWriterPermission": false,
    "createdDate": "2020-08-06T12:48:53.426Z",
    "modifiedDate": "2020-08-07T16:33:32.620Z",
    "modifiedByMeDate": "2020-08-06T12:48:53.426Z",
    "lastViewedByMeDate": "2020-08-06T12:48:53.426Z",
    "markedViewedByMeDate": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "version": "4",
    "parents": [{
      "kind": "drive#parentReference",
      "id": "1oSVTT56an_b9j_2v36YYL0RttSTMxacT",
      "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/12xY5YicH_xwEffZ3hKWSB-VRJXGKdr_C/parents/1oSVTT56an_b9j_2v36YYL0RttSTMxacT",
      "parentLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1oSVTT56an_b9j_2v36YYL0RttSTMxacT",
      "isRoot": false
    }],
    "userPermission": {
      "kind": "drive#permission",
      "etag": "\"48mYxyd7lvXVcFbAGXpkTSzlUPg\"",
      "id": "me",
      "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/12xY5YicH_xwEffZ3hKWSB-VRJXGKdr_C/permissions/me",
      "role": "owner",
      "type": "user"
    },
    "quotaBytesUsed": "0",
    "ownerNames": [
      "Eric Alderman"
    ],
    "owners": [{
      "kind": "drive#user",
      "displayName": "Eric Alderman",
      "picture": {
        "url": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14Gghb1AL4-QjAAp-0vkuLC6mVKen47uaGk326jyWMw=s64"
      },
      "isAuthenticatedUser": true,
      "permissionId": "18353875801874345244",
      "emailAddress": "xxxx@xxxx.com"
    }],
    "lastModifyingUserName": "Eric Alderman",
    "lastModifyingUser": {
      "kind": "drive#user",
      "displayName": "Eric Alderman",
      "isAuthenticatedUser": false,
      "permissionId": "01686054877458754075",
      "emailAddress": "xxx@xxx.com"
    },
    "capabilities": {
      "canCopy": false,
      "canEdit": true
    },
    "editable": true,
    "copyable": false,
    "writersCanShare": true,
    "shared": true,
    "explicitlyTrashed": false,
    "appDataContents": false,
    "spaces": [
      "drive"
    ]
  }]
}
```

Comment: Is Zappier the third party library you are using for calling Drive API methods or these are called separately?

Comment: Yes, Zapier.  This is the log from the Zapier execution.

Comment: Although I am using a third party tool, what I shared is the raw API submission and response to the Google Drive API which clearly demonstrates the unexpected behavior of the API.